# raphael multiple transformations on element

Tags: raphael, transform, scale

I'm trying to draw machinery from the bird's eye perspective.
Therefore, I draw rectangles. Theese rectangles may have angles (e.g. 90°, 270°). So i apply rotation transformation onto them. This way i can draw the whole plant.

Now if I apply scaling transformation onto the set, the elements are scaling. But the rotation transformations I previously applied, is running backwards.

Copy this to [raphael's playground](http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html) to see what i mean.

```
var rect1 = paper.rect(50,50,200,100).attr({fill: "green"});
var rect2 = paper.rect(250,50,200,100).attr({fill: "green"});
var rect3 = paper.rect(550,50,200,100).attr({fill: "green"});
rect3.transform("r90,550,50");

var set = paper.set();
set.push(rect1,rect2,rect3);
set.animate({'transform':"S0.5,0.5,50,50"}, 2000);
```

What I want now, is to prevent reversing the rotation and that the third elements alignment to second one stays as it is after rotation (some kind of "L").

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, got it myself. Using "..." solved my problem.

```
var rect1 = paper.rect(50,50,200,100).attr({fill: "green"});
var rect2 = paper.rect(250,50,200,100).attr({fill: "green"});
var rect3 = paper.rect(550,50,200,100).attr({fill: "green"});
rect3.transform("r90,550,50...");

var set = paper.set();
set.push(rect1,rect2,rect3);
set.animate({'transform':"...S0.5,0.5,50,50"}, 2000);
```

Tried it this way yesterday, but somehow it didnt work. Today, its working just fine =)

Comment: I didn't know about the ellipsis syntax, thank you! Transformations are such a headache.